# XPath returns null in c# but works in XPath validator

Tags: c#, validation, xpath, choetl

This is my first time using XPath.

This is my XML:

```
<content type="application/xml">
    <m:properties xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices">
        <d:Guid>YOIYOI-HNON-OIN</d:Guid>
        <d:ObjectId>6000009251</d:ObjectId>
        <d:ProcessType>ZMIN</d:ProcessType>
        <d:ProcessTypeTxt>Incident</d:ProcessTypeTxt>
        <d:Description>Test 2</d:Description>
        <d:IntroText>Incident</d:IntroText>
        <d:CreatedAtDateFormatted>08.05.18</d:CreatedAtDateFormatted>
        <d:ChangedAtDateFormatted>08.05.18</d:ChangedAtDateFormatted>
        <d:PostingDate>2018-05-08T00:00:00</d:PostingDate>
        <d:ChangedAtDate>2018-05-08T00:00:00</d:ChangedAtDate>
        <d:Priority>2</d:Priority>
        <d:PriorityTxt>2: High</d:PriorityTxt>
        <d:PriorityState>None</d:PriorityState>
        <d:Concatstatuser>New</d:Concatstatuser>
        <d:ActionRequired>false</d:ActionRequired>
        <d:StillOpen>true</d:StillOpen>
        <d:Icon></d:Icon>
        <d:SoldToPartyName></d:SoldToPartyName>
        <d:ServiceTeamName></d:ServiceTeamName>
        <d:PersonRespName></d:PersonRespName>
        <d:ConfigItemTxt></d:ConfigItemTxt>
    </m:properties>
</content>
```

There are other content nodes.

I need to retrieve specific tag values such as:

- d:Guid
- d:ProcessType
- d:Description
- and so on..

but I don't need all the tag values.

I tried an online Xpath validator where i posted my XML and used this expression:

```
//content/m:properties/d:Guid | //content/m:properties/d:ObjectId
```

This gives me the data that I needed but when I use it in c# application it returns null. Can somebody please explain to me why this happens? And if there's any other way to do so besides using XPath?

Here is my c# code :

```
string xml = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(startupPath);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

using (var node = ChoXmlReader.LoadText(xml).WithXPath("//content/m:properties/d:Guid or //content/m:properties/d:ObjectId"))
{
    using (var w = new ChoCSVWriter(sb).WithFirstLineHeader())
    {
        w.Write(node);
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please could you provide a [mcve]? We don't know what `ChoXmlReader` or `ChoCSVWriter` are - and the latter doesn't sound like it's relevant to the question. (But no, you don't need to use XPath to query XML. Personally I'd just use straight LINQ to XML.)

Comment: Based on your comments it sounds like you want to retrieve multiple nodes from the XML (d:Guid, d:ProcessType, etc) and write them to a CSV. The code you have now won't work, do you have to use `ChoETL`? If not @JonSkeet is correct that you'd be better off using LINQ to XML which has a lot of examples online.

Answer (score 0):

In the online validator you use `|` but you use `or` in your code. Does ChoETL really change the way XPaths work? I could not find evidence for that in the documentation.

Also, I think the online tool automatically deduces the namespace prefixes but you need to tell ChoETL the namespaces:

```
.WithXNamespace("d", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices")
```

and similar.

Comment: AFAIK, `|` should merge the result set while `or` returns a boolean expression, resulting in `true` if there is a node. If ChoETL changes that behavior, it would be quite surprising.

Comment: `using (var node = ChoXmlReader.LoadText(xml)
                .WithXPath("//content/m:properties/d:Guid | //content/m:properties/d:ObjectId")
                .WithXmlNamespace("m", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata")
                .WithXmlNamespace("d", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"))
            {
                using (var w = new ChoCSVWriter(sb).WithFirstLineHeader())
                {
                    w.Write(node);
                }
            }`

This still does not work :s

Comment: @lifeTech: "does not work" is not a very helful statement. What's the error message or result?

Comment: there is no error it does not even output the string on the console.

Comment: You definitely need to learn how to use a debugger. Sorry. I can't help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Model for this XML file and then serialize that to object and then access the properties you want. Here is the model you can use:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "properties", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata")]
    public class Properties
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Guid", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices")]
        public string Guid { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ObjectId", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices")]
        public string ObjectId { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ProcessType", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices")]
        public string ProcessType { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ProcessTypeTxt", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices")]
        public string ProcessTypeTxt { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Description", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "IntroText", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices")]
        public string IntroText { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "CreatedAtDateFormatted", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices")]
        public string CreatedAtDateFormatted { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ChangedAtDateFormatted", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices")]
        public string ChangedAtDateFormatted { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "PostingDate", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices")]
        public string PostingDate { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ChangedAtDate", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices")]
        public string ChangedAtDate { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Priority", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices")]
        public string Priority { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "PriorityTxt", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices")]
        public string PriorityTxt { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "PriorityState", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices")]
        public string PriorityState { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Concatstatuser", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices")]
        public string Concatstatuser { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ActionRequired", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices")]
        public string ActionRequired { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "StillOpen", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices")]
        public string StillOpen { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Icon", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices")]
        public string Icon { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "SoldToPartyName", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices")]
        public string SoldToPartyName { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ServiceTeamName", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices")]
        public string ServiceTeamName { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "PersonRespName", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices")]
        public string PersonRespName { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ConfigItemTxt", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices")]
        public string ConfigItemTxt { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "m", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string M { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "d", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string D { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "content")]
    public class Content
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "properties", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata")]
        public Properties Properties { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }
```

and here is the `C#` code to convert this to object:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Content));
 Content resultingMessage = (Content)serializer.Deserialize(new XmlTextReader(@"XMLFile1.xml"));
```

and this is the code to access guid property:

```
string guid = resultingMessage.Properties.Guid;
```

hope this solve your problem.

**PS:** I have created model based on your `XML` file given, if this `XML schema` changes you need to modify your `model` accordingly.

Happy coding...

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can output selective xml nodes to csv file using Cinchoo ETL

```
var nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
//register mapping of prefix to namespace uri 
nsManager.AddNamespace("m", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata");
nsManager.AddNamespace("d", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices");

StringBuilder csv = new StringBuilder();
using (var p = ChoXmlReader.LoadText(xml)
        .WithXPath("//entry/content/m:properties")
        .WithXmlNamespaceManager(nsManager)
        .WithField("Guid", xPath: "d:Guid")
        .WithField("ProcessType", xPath: "d:ProcessType")
        .WithField("Description", xPath: "d:Description")
    )
{
    using (var w = new ChoCSVWriter(csv)
        .WithFirstLineHeader()
        )
        w.Write(p);
}

Console.WriteLine(csv);
```